# Cant find AddHandler of PHP inside Apache configuration files

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I have a fresh install of CentOS (latest 8 and Stream 9) and I did this do install PHP and Apache:

```
dnf install httpd php
```

Everything works fine and PHP files are being interpreted correctly.

I realized there is a file at `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/20-php.conf` that loads PHP inside Apache using a line like:

```
LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so
```

Great! But I cant find anywhere else a code like `AddHandler xxxx php`. On all the previous times I installed PHP+Apache there always would be a line to load php using `AddHandler`.

I am asking this because I want to allow PHP to be interepreted in my entire server HOWEVER I dont want PHP to be interpreted if the user access any directory with name `dont_interpret_php`. In this case, if there is a PHP file inside this directory, it should be server by Apache `as is`, without interpreting its content.

I found some ways on Google to do that but all of them require modifying the line `AddHandler` but I cant find it anywhere (not in httpd.conf, not in virtualhosts file... no where!).

Thank you so much!

Comment: Here's a fragment from one of configurations (Apache/2.4.25):
`<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>`
Try `grep -R php` in your /etc/APACHE_CONFIG_DIR

Comment: @Jared YOU ARE RIGHT, grep found the entries I was looking for!!! If you post an answer, I will be glad to accept it!

Comment: Posted as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fragment from one of my configurations (Apache/2.4.25):

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
     SetHandler application/x-httpd-php 
</FilesMatch>
```

Try `grep -R php` in your /etc/APACHE_CONFIG_DIR